# onchange will run a function to create an html element the first time, but won't do it the second time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a chat program in javascript that doesn't show the next question until someone types an answer for the first question.

This function works to display the first question ("paragraph one") and then display the second question ("paragraph two"), but it won't work a third time.

I keep getting an error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null."

I have tried it with `onkeyup` and jquery's `.keyup()` function, but it gives me the same error. When I use the debugger to see the html that is generated, it shows the second paragraph, so I don't understand why the computer is saying it's null.

How can I solve this?

```
<div id = "div1">

</div>

<script>

   function setElement(text, id, id2){
   var para = document.createElement("p");
   var node = document.createTextNode(text);
   para.appendChild(node);
   var element = document.getElementById("div1");
   element.appendChild(para);
   para.id = id;
   var inputBox = document.createElement("input");
   element.appendChild(inputBox);
   inputBox.id = id2;
   }

   setElement("This is paragraph one.", "p1", "i1");

   document.getElementById("i1").onchange = function(){setElement("This     is paragraph two.", "p2", "i2")};

   document.getElementById("i2").onchange = function(){setElement("This is paragraph three.", "p3", "i3")};

   //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null
</script>
```

Comment: You're trying to get elements by ID with IDs that don't exist (i2). Unless this isnt your full code..

Comment: You are trying to access the "i2" element but you have not created it yet.

Comment: Keyword `addEventListener`.....

Comment: The paragraph with id "i2" is created when the function is run when someone adds input to the second paragraph. It even shows in the debugger.

Comment: Maybe you can't see it because I didn't format the code right in the display box, but the id of the input box is the third parameter of the function

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("i2").onchange = function(){setElement("This is paragraph three.", "p3", "i3")};
```

That element doesn't exist when the javascript runs so it throws an error.  You would need to run this line of code after creating the new element.

```
function setElement(pnum){
   var para = document.createElement("p");
   var node = document.createTextNode("this is paragraph " + pnum + ".");
   para.appendChild(node);
   var element = document.getElementById("div1");
   element.appendChild(para);
   para.id = "p" + pnum;
   var inputBox = document.createElement("input");
   element.appendChild(inputBox);
   inputBox.id = "i" + pnum;
         pnum++;
   inputBox.onchange = function(){setElement(pnum)};
}
setElement(1);
```

The above change will keep creating the paragraphs and input fields.

Comment: Had to modify that - I realized I had a mistake in the previous one that would put the wrong id on the paragraphs.

Comment: Also - are you sure you want to create a new paragraph every time a person edits an input?  Your code will create multiple duplicate "paragraph 2" and input fields if you keep modifying the content of "input 1".

Comment: This is a creative workaround, but what if I want to change the text? I tried using this code and adding text as a parameter, but it put all the elements up at once instead of waiting to add them after the onchange event.

Comment: As far as the multiple duplicate fields, the content of each input box is only meant to be modified once. It's a chat program. I made a program in java using NetBeans that worked great, but it was too complicated to make it run in a browser, so I'm trying to rewrite it in JavaScript. Is there an easier way to make a chat program using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish with this, but here is a simulation of a chat app that runs entirely in front-end javascript within a browser window.

```js
function setElement(caller){
   var outputs = document.getElementsByClassName("output");
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(outputs, function(o) {
     o.appendChild(makePara(caller, o));
     o.scrollTop = o.scrollHeight;
   });
   caller.value = "";
}
function makePara(caller, o) {
   var para = document.createElement("p");
   var node = document.createTextNode(caller.value);
   para.appendChild(node);
   if (o.parentElement != caller.parentElement.parentElement) {
     para.style.textAlign = "right";
     para.style.backgroundColor  = "#ffeeee";
   } else {
     para.style.textAlign = "left";
     para.style.backgroundColor  = "#eeffee";
   }
   return para;
}

var inputBox1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var inputBox2 = document.getElementById("input2");
inputBox1.onchange = function(){setElement(this)};
inputBox2.onchange = function(){setElement(this)};
```

```css
.chat { 
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }

.output {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="chat">
  <h4>Chat window 1</h4>
  <div id="txt1" class="output"></div>
  <div id="inpt1">
    <input type='text' id="input1" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div2" class="chat">
  <h4>Chat window 2</h4>
  <div id="txt2" class="output"></div>
  <div id="inpt2">
    <input type='text' id="input2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This will take me awhile to get through. I posted an answer to my specific problem, but I am going to study this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with, thanks to Momus and https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display_js. Thanks also to everybody who kept telling me the elements didn't exist yet. I decided to make them exist first, and then use javascript to show them.

```
<div id = "div1">

<p id = "p1" style = "display:none;">Hi, I'm RiddleBot. What is your name?</p>
<input id = "i1" type = "text" style = "display:none;">
<p id = "p2" style = "display: none;">Hi. What do you like to do?</p>
<input id = "i2" type = "text" style = "display:none;">
<p id = "p3" style = "display: none;">I like to tell riddles. Do you want to hear one?</p>
<input id = "i3" type = "text" style = "display:none;">
<p id = "p4" style = "display: none;">In marble walls as white as...</p>
<input id = "i4" type = "text" style = "display:none">

</div>

<script>


 function showElement(pnum){
 var inputBox = document.getElementById("i" + pnum);
 document.getElementById("p" + pnum).style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("i" + pnum).style.display = "block";
 pnum++;
 inputBox.onchange = function () {showElement(pnum)};
 }

 showElement(1);

 </script>
```